# Laravel sail ./vendor/bin/sail up -d errorcode 100

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS «Jammy Jellyfish»
I have installed laravel project via `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`

after process was finished i entered to 'example-app' subfolder and runned `./vendor/bin/sail up`

the process was failed with errorcode 100

it looks like docker loadader wrong images or smth like this. Docker version is

> Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc

full console output:

```
    [+] Running 1/1
     ! laravel.test Warning                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
    [+] Building 65.0s (8/15)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     => [laravel.test internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                              0.2s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
     => [laravel.test internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.3s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
     => [laravel.test internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                                                                                                                                   1.7s
     => [laravel.test  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:aabed3296a3d45cede1dc866a24476c4d7e093aa806263c27ddaadbdce3c1054                                                                                           0.0s
     => [laravel.test internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                 0.3s
     => => transferring context: 99B                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
     => CACHED [laravel.test  2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
     => CACHED [laravel.test  3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone                                                                                                                 0.0s
     => ERROR [laravel.test  4/11] RUN apt-get update     && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librs  62.8s
    ------                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     > [laravel.test  4/11] RUN apt-get update     && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip 
    unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librsvg2-bin fswatch     && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee 
    /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://
ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > 
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev        php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd php8.2-imagick        php8.2-curl        php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring        php8.2-xml php8.2-zip 
    php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap        php8.2-intl php8.2-readline        
php8.2-ldap        php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole        php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug     && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-
    dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg     && echo "deb [signed-
    by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y 
    nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && npm install -g pnpm     && npm install -g bun     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-
    by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee 
    /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-15     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
    0.978 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
    1.134 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
    1.248 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    60.89 Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.2) ...
    61.18 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.140703003843184'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
    61.18  installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    61.40 Errors were encountered while processing:
    61.40  python3.10-minimal
    61.42 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    ------
    failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librsvg2-bin fswatch    
     && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] 
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install 
    -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev        php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd php8.2-imagick        php8.2-curl        php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring        php8.2-xml php8.2-zip php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap        php8.2-intl php8.2-readline        php8.2-ldap        
php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole        php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug     && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-
    dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_VERSION.x 
    nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && npm install -g pnpm     && npm install -g bun     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | 
    tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && curl -sS 
    https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > 
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf 
    /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
```

I have tryed to fix it by
`sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/`,
`sudo apt-get update`,
`sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up`,
`sudo apt-get upgrade` etc.

i have also enough space on disc.

Comment: > `60.89 Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.2) ...
    61.18 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10` <<<=== your local system. Is it windows with WSL2 or Linux? What happens if you run `sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up`

Comment: @UnderDog Ubuntu 22.04 LTS «Jammy Jellyfish», absolutely same result when try 'sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up'

Comment: Bring your Dockerfile over from the vendor directory to tour local directory. In sail, there must be a `publish` command somewhere that does that. Edit your Dockerfile. The command failed while running a python3 command, but look at the `apt-get install` it was doing. Remove some things there (add them later) maybe postures. Your goal is to make the 'build' work. If you're using mysql, you don't need postgres. First make things work, then add things if needed

Comment: I`m not sure what was the problem but i installed earlier version of node via nvm and corresponding npm version and it helped, probably it was just a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed earlier version of node (14.21.3) via nvm and corresponding npm version (6.14.18) and the problem has been solved.